# Does "module ClassMethods" has any special meaning in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I came cross this code in ruby on rails:

```
class Person
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  attr_accessor :name, :email

  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 100 }
end
```

My question is what makes this "validates" method callable in this class Person, in order for us to call "validates" within class context, this "validates" method must be defined in any of the following three places:

1. "class Class"
2. "class Module"
3. Person's eigenclass.

So I try to find if any of those cases are true, the only thing here is this line:

```
  include ActiveModel::Validations
```

When I look at the source code of ActiveModel::Validations, validates is not defined directly in ActiveModel::Validations, but it is defined in ActiveModel::Validations::ClassMethods, so from what I see here, this struct definitely can not add validates methods to any of the above 3 places, the only suspect is this module name: ClassMethods, from its name, it looks like all its method will be defined in the eigenclass of the class which mix-in it, but I didn't find any code that actually does that.

So my question is: is this module name: ClassMethods has any special meaning in rails?
When we mix-in ActiveModel::Validations, does rails automatically find all the methods in ActiveModel::Validations::ClassMethods, and add those into the eigenclass of the current class?

Thanks.

Comment: `ActiveModel::Validations`that is included int your class [`extend ActiveSupport::Concern`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/activemodel/lib/active_model/validations.rb#L38). When using Concern then the `ClassMethods` module is handled by the concern and its methods are added to the class. Read more about [concerns](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html).

Comment: thanks this code " base.extend ClassMethods" is what I am looking.